# Error from scapy.all import *

Tags: python

Eu estou tentando mexer com Scapy mas quando tento usar ele
`from scapy.all import` aparece este erro.

```
    from scapy.all import *
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Lucas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scapy\all.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .arch import *
  File "C:\Users\Lucas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from .windows import *
  File "C:\Users\Lucas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\windows\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from scapy.arch import pcapdnet
  File "C:\Users\Lucas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\pcapdnet.py", line 32, in <module>
    from .winpcapy import *
  File "C:\Users\Lucas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\winpcapy.py", line 26, in <module>
    _lib=CDLL('wpcap.dll')
  File "C:\Users\Lucas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] Não foi possível encontrar o módulo especificado
```

Comment: Você possui o pacote `scapy` instalado? Se sim, como instalou? Como se certificou que ele está instalado? Aliás, existe o caractere `*` após `import`?

Comment: Eu instalei o `scapy` através do prompt do windows e no shell quando dou `import scapy` ele importa sem erros mas quando do o `scapy.all` ele não vai  estou vendo esse comando através de um curso de python e ele usa essa função normalmente.

Comment: Instalei o Scapy aqui e me parece que ele não possui um módulo chamado `all`. Tem certeza que é este o nome?

Comment: Então quando ele utiliza o comando ele funciona normalmente. como no print (http://prntscr.com/fbsakb)

Comment: Estranho que aqui o módulo `all` não é instalado fazendo desta forma. Você executou o programa com Python 3 também?

Comment: Passou a reconhecer o módulo `all` depois que instalei o [WinPCap](https://www.winpcap.org/install/default.htm)

Comment: Um amigo disse que pelo windows dava erro então fiz Dual Boot e utilizei o Mint ai funcionou normalmente. E sim estava utilizando o python 3 !!